# How to configure Goland IDE to *not* warn about "<Symbol> redeclared in this package" error

Tags: go, goland

I'm using Goland IDE to write various simple, experimental Go programs to improve my understanding of Go and to do various other exercises.

I have a directory containing N different Go files, that are all completely independent. Each file is in package "main", and each has a main function. I can independently invoke each Go file from within Goland.

Unfortunately, Goland doesn't think that all these "main" files are independent, and it is showing errors when the the same symbol is declared in two different files. Is there any way to stop Goland from displaying this error ?

I could work around the problem by placing each Go file in a separate directory, but it seems an overkill to have a directory for each different simple, experimental Go program.

Answer (score 1):

Goland is technically correct. All files in the same directory, with the same `package pkgname` statement belong to the same package. The fact that you run them, causing individual file compilation, with the equivalent of `go run myfile.go` is the main reason you are not seeing any problems when running them.